Why quantization noise correlates with the signal based on the sampling frequency to signal frequency ratio?
I've been the reading the walt kester's "Taking the Mystery out of the Infamous Formula,
"SNR = 6.02N + 1.76dB," and Why You Should Care", In page 5/7,he mentioned,
the correlation between the quantization noise and the signal depends upon the ratio of
the sampling frequency to the input signal.
He also gave an example about it,

Result:

When frequency is 2MHz the harmonics are more prominent compared to when the frequency is 2.111MHz.

Why does the quantization noise correlates with the input frequency
when it is 2MHz and not 2.111MHz?
2.111MHz is not a multiple of the fundamental frequency, what's so significant about this?
It is mentioned that the noise is concentrated on the harmonics,
Why?.


Walt Kester's tutorial is very good in giving a nice intuitive explanation of the three claims you reiterate in your question. If you are longing for a rigorous math of an equidistribution phenomenon as it connects with sampling theory, Fourier series etc., see, for example, https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_2015-16/08_Fourier-Weyl.pdf and further on with keywords you can learn from the ref.


2.111MHz is not a multiple of the fundamental frequency...

There is no such claim in the tutorial, because it does not make sense: for a 2.111MHz input signal, 2.111MHz is a fundamental frequency. Or maybe you want to say that it is not a multiple because a multiplier here is exactly one?

It is mentioned that the noise is concentrated at the harmonics...

It is not just mentioned, it is explained more than once (page 3, 1st para, and page 5, 1st and 3rd para). But the most remarkable piece is the section SNR, PROCESS GAIN, AND FFT NOISE FLOOR RELATIONSHIPS (page 6-7), where the narrative does not mention harmonics explicitly. Still, it is the crucial part of the tutorial. In fact, the author claims and effectively proves that the 2MHz and 2.111MHz cases differ only in that with a 4096-point FFT for a 2MHz input signal you can clearly see harmonics in the frequency spectrum plot while for a 2.111MHz input signal the harmonics merge into a noise-like background and are indistinguishable. To detect harmonics with a 2.111MHz input signal you have to have a larger FFT; say, 4,194,304 samples may suffice.
In reality, in order to accurately measure the harmonic distortion of an 80MHz clocked ADC with a 2.111MHz input signal you would require not just the FFT size large enough, but also sufficiently low Johnson noise, ADC DNL/INL stability figures etc. But these factors are also important for the 2MHz case, only the requirements are less stringent. Effectively, these interferences contribute as a small amount of noise which you sum (dither) with the input signal in order to eliminate the artifacts due to quantization noise correlation (page 6, right above the section SNR, PROCESS GAIN, AND FFT NOISE FLOOR RELATIONSHIPS). In their absence, the harmonics are always present -- if the single-tone-wave-frequency-to-sampling-frequency ratio is a rational number. The role of this delicate matter (frequency ratio rationality/irrationaly) can be investigated further, but for all practical matters Walt Kester's tutorial gives exhaustive, very useful explanation.
With a due attention to wording, one can say that the quantization noise correlates with the input frequency both for 2MHz and 2.111MHz single-tone waves, only the depth of this correlation differs for the two cases and therefore the practical implications for measurements.

Now that i've re-read it and along with your answer, i think i understood. If the input signal is multiple of the sampling frequency (they are harmonically related) the harmonics will have a higher magnitude compared to when they are not harmonically related. So, frequencies like 2.1MHz, 2.12MHz, 2.3MHz ... etc will have harmonics but they are hidden by the FFT noise floor, lowering the floor by considering more samples will make it visible.

In the plot, is the reason why in (a) the floor slides down 10's of dB compared to (b)  is because the energy being concentrated in the harmonics?.

Try and simulate sampling a single-tone wave with varying tone and ADC frequencies. The simulation is free of common noise sources and you see pure "quantization noise"-contribution plots. It might become an instructive experience.

Here's something i don't quite understand, maybe i missed it yet again but why does the quantization noise strongly correlates with the signal when the signal frequency and the sampling frequency is harmonically related?

Try to look at it the other way: the harmonics correlates with the non-linear signal distortions. What signal distortions and why these are non-linear? Take a direct conversion ADC. It is a bank of threshold detectors each tuned to fire for a pre-determined voltage range, and the threshold detector is a non-linear circuit (its output is not a linear function of its input). So, intrinsically, analog-to-digital converter (and its output) is a non-linear operator mapping a source voltage to data output. i.e., the output of even ideal ADC is not proportional all the way to the input.

Quite naturally, the distortion of this mapping is due to the converter, not to the source signal. But these are just "words, words, words"; they won't help you design a circuit or code a microprogram or process the measurement results. True understanding of these presumably delicate matters comes with practical experience.

Documents of content and quality like Walt Kester's tutorial contribute greatly to your education, but those must accompany intense exercises in circuit design, coding or signal processing, what of this list accommodates your major.


Why does the quantization noise correlates with the input frequency when it is 2MHz and not 2.111MHz?

Because 2MHz sampled at 80 MHz is periodic in discrete time. You only use few sample values (21 in this case) and repeat them over and over again. So the quantization noise also takes on only 21 different values and it also is periodic. Hence is has a discrete spectrum that's only non-zero at integer multiples of 2 MHz.
2.111 MHz sampled at 80 MHz is NOT periodic in discrete time. You sample pretty much all possible values of the sine wave and the quantization noise takes on all possible values in a more or less random order. That makes it uncorrelated and whit with roughly equal energy at all frequencies

2.111MHz is not a multiple of the fundamental frequency, what's so significant about this?

Because that's determines whether its periodic in discrete time or not. See the point above.

It is mentioned that the noise is concentrated on the harmonics, Why?.

It's only concentrated in harmonics if the quantization is periodic. Periodic signal in time have a discrete spectrum. That's the fundamental idea behind the Fourier Series.
